# Windows Phone 8.1 Weird text displayed when first item is selected on combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML Application (C#). On some of the combo boxes on this application, when the user selected the first item on the combobox, the combobox displays a class name, instead of the actual item that the user selects. For e.g. one of the combo boxes is defined like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Ages}" Name="minAgeComboBox" />
```

Which is being filled from xaml.cs like this:

```
var list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 18; i <= 99; i++) list.Add(i.ToString());
DefaultViewModel["Ages"] = list;
minAgeComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

When the user presses submit button, I am getting the value of the combobox like this:

```
var minAge = minAgeComboBox.SelectedItem as string;
```

When I run this application, the combo box correctly displayes "18" as selected item. When I tap on the combo box, I am presented with a list of numbers from 18 to 99. Everything is fine up to this point. But when I select the first item, which is 18, from the list, the list closes and the combo box displays

```
MyAppName.ObservableDictionary
```

If I press submit button when the combo box is like this, the c# code still correctly reads the selected item text as "18". The only thing broken is the text on the combo box.

Is this a bug? Is there a known resolution or workaround for this?

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28199771/2681948).

Comment: Yes. And the workaround there fixed my problem. Thanks.